# In which RFC can I find the TCP/IPV4 flags bits first defined?

Tags: tcp, ipv4, rfc

I'm trying to find the definition of the TCP/IP4 flags bits, can someone tell me where I can find it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it here

[RFC 791 - section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791#page-13)